# SQL Server insert EXCEPT without selecting from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert some people into a user table using:

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable] (col2, col3)  
VALUES ('Jim', 'Bob'),
       ('Stinky', 'Pete'),
       ('Old', 'Frank')
```

I don't want those entries entered if they already exist (there is an ID column, but the uniqueness here should be dictated by a composite of those two columns.

If I was selecting these values from a table I could use (I think):

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable] (col2, col3)
   SELECT [Name1], [Name2] 
   FROM [ExistingTable]
   EXCEPT 
   SELECT [col2], [col3] 
   FROM [MyTable]
```

So how can I do this `EXCEPT` clause when my data isn't in a table already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should have the *database* validate uniqueness:

```
create unique index unq_mytable_id on mytable(id);
```

This is not needed if `id` is already declared as a primary key -- which, presumably, it should be.

Then, you can just include a list using `values()`:

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable] (col2, col3)
   SELECT v.*
   FROM (VALUES ('Jim','Bob'), ('Stinky','Pete'), ('Old','Frank')
        ) v(col2, col3)
   EXCEPT
   SELECT col2, col3
   FROM mytable;
```

Of course, `NOT EXISTS` also works, but this is closer to your original query.

Comment: Yes! I knew I'd used something like this last year I just couldn't figure out the danged syntax and was going round in circles. Thanks! And yes col 1 is the primary key Id

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cte` with `not exists` :

```
with cte as (
      select t.*
      from ( values ('Jim','Bob'), ('Stinky','Pete'), ('Old','Frank') 
           ) t(col2, col3)
     )
INSERT INTO [MyTable] (col2,col3)
   select c.col2, c.col3
   from cte c
   where not exists (select 1 from mytable t where t.col2 = c.col2 and t.col3 = c.col3);
```

Comment: @jamheadart. . . Yes.

Comment: Doesn't like  `SELECT 1 FROM TABLE t` - I'm on 2008 here I wonder if that's an issue.

Comment: @jamheadart. . .  I fixed the table-name & alias. This should work.